# Access RadiobuttonList control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to access ASP.net radiobuttonlist control options in .js file.
I try all previous links but it does't work.

Here I m looking to pass client id to js function and use that to access value associated with that radiobuttonlist.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Win, set ClientIDMode to Static

then you need to know that this is just a single element, the options also are elements inside

so now you need to iterate throught the nested elements, something like:

```
var myRadioButtonList = document.getElementById("<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>");

var rblName = myRadioButtonList.name;

var radioOptionElements = document.getElementsByName(rblName);

// Then loop through the array of elements :
   for (var x = 0; x < radioOptionElements.length; x ++) 
    {
        alert(radioOptionElements[x].id);
        if (radioOptionElements[x].checked) 
            {
                alert("You checked " + radioOptionElements[x].id);
            }
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, I already try that but the "checked" generate error here.

Answer (score 0):

Make ClientIDMode to Static so that ID won't change when you access from js file.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RadioButtonList1" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```